# Remainder Estimate for Integral Test

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The question is to estimate the error for the series 
$$\sum_{n\to1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+1}$$
using the Remainder Estimate for the Integral Test:
$$\int_{n+1}^\infty f(x)\,dx\le R_n\le\int_n^\infty f(x)\,dx$$
I did some hand calculations to determine that $n\ge 2000$  shows that the remainder $R_n\le0.0005$

I then tried:

```
s = Sum[1/(n^2 + 1), {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]
Assuming[n > 1, 
 Reduce[s - Sum[1/(1 + k^2), {k, 1, n}] < 0.0005, n, Integers]]
```

But that did not work. Does anyone have good suggestions how to use Mathematica to determine the remainder of this series?

Comment: not sure I understand exactly what the question is, but you need ~2000 terms to have `r<0.0005` ( I just did `Table[s-Sum..{n}]` )

Comment: Are you looking for an expression that bounds the tail for any n? The Euler Mclaurin summation formula is one cute way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions say to use the integral remainder estimate.

```
tailUpper[n_] := Integrate[1/(x^2 + 1), {x, n, ∞}]
Reduce[tailUpper[n] <= Rationalize[0.0005], n, Integers]
(*  n ∈ Integers && n >= 2000  *)
```

Now get bounds on the error estimate:

```
tailLower[n_] := Integrate[1/(x^2 + 1), {x, n + 1, ∞}]
{tailLower[2000], tailUpper[2000]} // N

(*  {0.00049975, 0.0005}  *)
```

Comment: Nice answer. This will be quite easy for my students to understand. Much appreciated.